# I want to count frequency or occurrence of a every letter in a string C program

Tags: c, string, logic

Suppose if I pass a string like `"I am Programmer"`.

If a letter has occurred one time it should print `"I has occurred 1 time"`, or else if a letter appears twice in the string it should print `"a has occurred 2 times"`, `"m has occurred 3 times"` and so on for every letter in the string. I searched it and found in some website. Is there any way we could rewrite the code because I didn't understand the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char string[100];
   int c = 0, count[26] = {0};

   printf("Enter a string\n");
   gets(string);

   while (string[c] != '\0')
   {
      /** Considering characters from 'a' to 'z' only
          and ignoring others */

      if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z') 
         count[string[c]-'a']++;

      c++;
   }

   for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   {
      /** Printing only those characters 
          whose count is at least 1 */

      if (count[c] != 0)
         printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'a',count[c]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what's the question? And What have you tried?

Comment: I have searched in many sites but I didn't understand the logic Mr.Cool Guy

Comment: [Really?](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=frequenct%20letter%20c%20string)

Comment: int main()
{
   char string[100];
   int c = 0, count[26] = {0};
 
   printf("Enter a string\n");
   gets(string);
 
   while (string[c] != '\0')
   {
      /** Considering characters from 'a' to 'z' only
          and ignoring others */
 
      if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z') 
         count[string[c]-'a']++;
 
      c++;
   }
 
   for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   {
      /** Printing only those characters 
          whose count is at least 1 */
 
      if (count[c] != 0)
         printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'a',count[c]);
   }
 
   return 0;
}

Comment: Please indent and format your code and add it to your question. Also, specify the problem with it.

Comment: never (!) use `gets()`. Even in an example or in an one-off program. (they tend to go into production and are never corrected)

Comment: I'm sorry Mr.Peter Miehele I'm just a beginner in coding. So I want you guys to help.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about the logic?  What part of the code is tripping you up?  Yes, there is room for improvement (`gets` opens a *major* security hole and is no longer supported, this code only counts lower-case characters), but you need to tell us what you don't understand, otherwise any suggestions for improvement won't make sense.

Comment: I didn't understand while loop condition Mr.John Bode and what is the going on in that loop and what if we sent combination of uppercase and lowercase letters as input can we find out the occurrences of that letter. Is there any way we could try to rewrite the code for easy understanding. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the rewrite, the original code is better but this one might be easier to understand:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char cur_char;
   char string[100];
   int index = 0, count[255] = {0};

   printf("Enter a string\n");
   gets(string);


   while (string[index] != '\0')
   {
      char cur_char = string[index];

      // cur_char is a char but it acts as the index of the array like
      // if it was an unsigned short
      count[cur_char] = count[cur_char] + 1;

      index++;
   }

   for (index = 0; index < 255; index++)
   {
      if (count[index] != 0)
         printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n", index, count[index]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the code Mr.Sephiazck. That would be very helpful for me to understand the code

Answer (score 0):

A variable type *char* can be considered as an integer (it's how they are stored in the memory anyway) so you can write:

```
int test = 'a';
printf("%i", test);
```

And it will print you *97*. Also letters from a to z are represented by continuous intergers, that means 'b' = 98. So taht also means **'b' - 'a' = 1**

In your solution, they create an array of 26 integers to count the occurence of each letters betwin 'a' and 'z' (note that they ignore all others including A-Z by doing this)

They decided that in the array *count*, index 0 is here to count occurences of a, 1 for b .... 25 for z, that explains this:

```
count[string[c]-'a']++;
```

If *string[c]* is a *b* then *string[c]-'a' = 1* so we have our index for count array and increase the amount of occurence of *b*.

So all you need to understand this code is that you can manipulate a char like an int basically, you should make a quick search about what is ASCII code as well.

If you still need a rewrite of this code to understand, tell me.

Comment: Mr.Sephizack thank you for explaining the code to me and so generous of you. Yes I would like you to rewrite the code so that I could understand the code in easy manner.