# At least two times

Tags: c

I'm doing part where I just can't figure out how can I count if at least 2 times some character has shown up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    unsigned long int zbrojz=0;

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
      if((c == 'Z' >= 2) || (c == 'z' >= 2)){
            zbrojz++;
      }
    }
    printf("Z ili z je se pojavilo: %lu puta", zbrojz);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a histogram?

Comment: @StoryTeller Little bit

Comment: What StoryTeller intended to say: Make an array which provides as much elements as you want to check. Initialize it with all 0's. When you check a character you increment the corresponding cell in the array. If you check a cell in that array it tells you how often the corresponding character appeared.

Comment: Yet another hint: `'A'` ... `'Z'` form a consecutive range [64 + 1, 64 + 26], as well as `'a'` ... `'z'` a consecutive range [96 + 1, 96 + 26] assuming that your platform supports [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). Alternatively, you can use an array of 256 elements and simply count every character you read from input where (value of) character is simply used as index in array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845805/i-want-to-count-frequency-or-occurrence-of-a-every-letter-in-a-string-c-program

Comment: I kinda figured it out, now I have a problem with assigning two characters(z,Z) to char.

Comment: @Arthuoff what exactly is the program supposed to do?

Comment: @Jabberwocky To count if at least two times some character has shown up, in this example it's (z or Z)

Comment: @Arthuoff You can also use [`toupper()` or `tolower()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.2.1) to simplify your code by converting the character read to a consistent case so all you have to to is compare it once.  For example:  `if ( 'Z' == toupper( c ) ) zbrojz++;`

Comment: Also, `while((c = getchar()) != '\n') ...` will go into an infinite loop if you hit `EOF` before you reach a `\n` character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I guessed right what the program is supposed to do (show the number of 'Z' or 'z' occuring in your input), the condition is wrong.

It should be:

```
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
  {
    if ((c == 'Z') || (c == 'z')) {   /// <<< changes on this line
      zbrojz++;
    }
  }
```

Input:

```
abcZzdeZ
```

Output:

```
Z ili z je se pojavilo: 3 puta
```

Comment: This is good example, but it counts total of z or Z. I need it to print only if it appeared at least two times, else it won't print anything.

Comment: @Arthuoff it shouldn't be too hard to figure out that one. Hint: do the `printf` only if `zbrojz` is larger than 2.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can't predict during the loop just how many 'z'/'Z' characters your program will receive, you need to count all occurrences of 'z' or 'Z' and then test the count before outputting anything:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    unsigned long int zbrojz=0;

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n')
      if(c == 'Z' || c == 'z')
            zbrojz++;

    if(zbrojz >= 2)
      printf("Z ili z je se pojavilo: %lu puta\n", zbrojz);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes it's like this, solved it by previous hint, thanks anyway